# google spreadsheet Real time importrange not reliable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 google spreadsheet

1. a membership database // with 8 column of data for 1 record. Currently there are around 3000 record in the sheet and it is growing at a rate of around 1500 records per month. New members enter these info via a google form. And then I wrote some apps script to assign membership number to each record in numeric order e.g. KS000001--->KS000002 with onSubmit trigger.
2. a sales record // which import the entire membership database with function importrange and record sales.

Whenever I enter a sales record, I need to check if he is a registered member in real time and match the sales record with the respective membership number.

Sometimes the importrange just doesnt work and shows #REF
This is the function I use

=ImportRange("xxxxsheetidxxxxxx","Membership DB!A1:I5000")

Is there a more reliable way to do this? I need this in real time for today newly joined member.
The idea I have in mind is to cut the database into two parts and update it everynight.

Method:
Copy the entire membership database to the sales record at 12:00am. e.g. record (KS000001-KS003000). Use importrange to import the newly joined member during the day e.g. record (KS003001 - latest). Both array are in the same column A:I for easier look up.

Is there any better alternatives?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any reliable alternative to ImportRange() in new google spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348154/is-there-any-reliable-alternative-to-importrange-in-new-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: sorry it doesn't help. I really need this update almost real time